# vertically centering search box in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Backgroud::** i am having a really though problem vertically aligning a search box , its kind of a tough nut to crack and i have been at this for a few hours , the HTML markup is clean , have a look at it ::

**Problem::** I have been using the `display:table` and `display:table-cell` properties to get the search box to align vertically,  have a look at the markup :

```
<header>
    <img src="http://www.freestockphotos.name/wallpaper-original/wallpapers/download-images-of-gentle-dogs-6866.jpg" alt="image of laminates"> 
            <div class="location-search-container">
                <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                     </span>
                 </div><!-- /input-group -->    
            </div>

</header>
```

Note that header is `position:relative`, `img` is `display:block` and `location-search-container` is where the difficulty lies , its positioned absolutly and has the following CSS applied ::

```
.location-search-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}
```

theoretically the search box should be positioned in the middle , but its not , see the result in the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnjvo9nz/)** ::

Now , a little tweak , lets remove the image element and add the following additional properties to the `header` element ::

```
header {
    position: relative;
    /*add the below two properties*/
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

now see how the search box is centered (**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bnjvo9nz/1/)**). I am relatively pretty new to CSS and this one is a though nut to crack . can somebody tell me what am i missing ?

I know this is going to take some effort , so thank you for your time and patience.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't combine `position: absolute` and `display: table` and get the results you're expecting. Instead, set a 50% top position and a negative top margin on the search box equal to half its height:

```
.location-search-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.input-group {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -17px;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bnjvo9nz/4)**

Comment: ! did quite get the Math , why 30% why not 50% ? , i know 30 works perfect , but how ? ..... anyways ! thanks and +1 , your solution is awesome !

Comment: Top padding uses the width of the parent, while top uses the height. That's a better method that I'd forgotten about.

Comment: As I said, top padding uses the parent's *width* as a basis. Depending on aspect ratio, it must be lager or smaller than half the parent height.

Comment: you say `You can't combine position: absolute and display: table and get the results you're expecting` , but clearly here  http://jsfiddle.net/bnjvo9nz/1/ , i get the result  , i don't mean to argue , i'am just confused :D

Comment: ! last request , can you edit your answer with both the solutions , as i liked the 1st one better ! , and then i'll accept your answer ! . Thanks  genius !